# Mongoose; sort so that a certain record appears first

Tags: sorting, mongoose

The code beneath takes a user's id and finds the categories the said user is subscribed to.

As of now, I send the categories sorted after the date they were created. The first category I created and the first category I want to send, in an array of categories, is 'all'.

I was wondering if there was a way to find the category with the `categoryName` that is 'all', and send it first.

This is my code:

```
const userItemList = async ({userId})=> {
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
return Category.find({ categoryName: { $in: user.addedCategories }})
    .sort([['createdAt', 1]])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your result alphabetically by `categoryName`:

```
const userItemList = async ({userId})=> {
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
return Category.find({ categoryName: { $in: user.addedCategories }})
    .sort([['categoryName', 1]])
}
```

Or simply use:

```
Category.find({ categoryName: 'all'}).sort([['createdAt', 1]])
```